# Yeoman, ran yo webapp, grunt throwing error

Tags: node.js, yeoman

I ran 'yo webapp' and am now trying to run grunt serve and get the error that is below. Has anyone seen this error before?

```
grunt serve

module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'findup-sync'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous>    (/Users/william/wdi/pixelect_project/pixelect_client_server/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/file.js:24:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably forgetting about installing the dependencies. Try to install the dependencies using bower before running grunt.

Try to run this:`bower install`.

Comment: I ran bower install and I am still getting the same error. any thoughts?

Comment: Check your package.json to verify that all the mentioned dependencies are present.